# Want to add a one-to-one column to an existing table

Tags: python, mysql, django, alter-table

I have a new field in the Client called note which has a one-to-one relation with Notes.
I want to be able to add the note column under the Client table in mysql. It does not work when I use `python manage.py syncdb`. So I would like to know how to add a one-to-one field in mysql to an existing table.

**models.py**

```
class Note(models.Model):
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    user  = models.ForeignKey(User)
    note = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.name)

class Client(models.Model):
    note = models.OneToOneField(Note) # new
    def __unicode__(self)
       return unicode(self.user)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syncdb doesn't change your database in order not to destroy your data. See [django book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/1.0/chapter05/#cn262).

You can update the database manually or use an automated migration tool (at your own risk) like [South](http://south.aeracode.org/).

EDIT:
In [django book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/1.0/chapter05/#cn262), you can also read detailed instructions about manual changes along with SQL examples. Other useful information can be found in [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html).

Comment: I am assuming you can use `alter tables` command if you do it manually but I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: Your best bet is to just use South. I have found that it works pretty well (even if it is a bit confusing to use at first). Make sure to make a backup of your tables before you perform the migration though.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what the application name is so I'll assume it is fooapp.

First look at the SQL Django would have used to create the relevant tables:

```
python manage.py sql fooapp
```

For additional fields run this sql command:

```
ALTER TABLE fooapp_client ADD ...
```

where ... is the field declaration you saw in the output of "manage.py sql fooapp"

Remember to also execute any index/constraint commands in the "manage.py sql fooapp" output that operate on the new field.

Comment: steyn: If I run `python manage.py sql mmc ` I get `ALTER TABLE `mmc_note` ADD CONSTRAINT `user_id_refs_id_68316a64` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `auth_user` (`id`);` and in the table `note_id` integer NOT NULL UNIQUE`. But in mysql, the table for client did not update. Can you give me the full command for alter table for a one-to-one relationship for note under Client table.